# rust: If an enum has all variants derived from a generic struct, what's the best way to inspect the generic stored in the enum?

Tags: enums, rust, variant

I've condensed things down to where I have a Generic Adapter, which is stored in an enum, that is non-generic. This looks like:

```
enum Collective {
    StateTable(Adapter<StateTable>),
    TestMessage(Adapter<TestMessage>)
}
```

I have getters and setters for Adapter, and I've stored Collective values in vector. While I can use match, to crack things out, via the following, I'm wondering if there isn't a better way.

```
impl Collective {
    fn get_id(&self) -> u128 {
        match self {
            ReceiverAdapters::StateTable(a) => a.get_id(),
            ReceiverAdapters::TestMessage(a) => a.get_id(),
        }
    }
```

I've considered From, but not sure if that will help. I'm also concerned with maintenance, as the number of variants grows. Can anyone provide an alternate to match? Or is match, under the covers compiling down to near-zero code in this case?

Comment: I've since added a trait to the Adapter(s) in an attempt to normalize them. However, I've yet to find a way to call through the trait without running match.